# HTML email: making it work both in Outlook and on mobile

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am writing a template for html email (God have mercy on my soul). The design looks simple enough — there is this centrally aligned block with some text and images:

[image]

Nothing too fancy, no multi-column layout or anything, and yet, I am stuck. Here’s what's giving me problems:

- On desktop screens, the central block should be 480px wide.
- On mobile phones, in portrait orientation (that's less than 480px), the central block should take the whole width of the screen

So my approach to this problem (borrowed from / inspired by other templates) was to create a table with 100% width, with another table inside, also 100% width, and a max-width of 480px, like so:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width: 100%; max-width: 480px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
               Some blah
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It works on mobile. It works in browser clients. It works in Thunderbird. It works in Apple Mail. It makes me smile. But of course, Outlook can't do max-width, so it blows up the central block to 100% width.

So how could I modify my code to make this design also work correctly in that abomination that is Outlook?

**EDIT:** This is what I was getting on mobile phone screens in portrait orientation when I just set the width of the internal table to 480px:

[image]

Comment: Why not make one that works in outlook and then use media queries for the rest?

Comment: Because Gmail throws away the styles from the `head`, and you can't do inline media queries? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [this trick from elidickinson](https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/5525752):

```
<!--[if mso]>
<center>
<table><tr><td width="480"> 
<![endif]--> 
<div style="max-width:480px; margin:0 auto;">
   ...
</div> 
<!--[if mso]> 
</td></tr></table> 
</center> 
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Looks promising! I will try.

Comment: Got to testing the trick you suggested only now, and it worked. Only I changed the `div` in your solution to `table` to keep my initial formatting.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you do like this

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table bgcolor="#f00" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="480">
               Some blah
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I started with this approach. It, however, gave me problems on mobile phones in the portrait mode, because the internal table became wider than the screen width.

Comment: I updated my question to demonstrate what the problem was.

Comment: @azangru Updated with an alternative, where you add width to the cell instead like this `<td width="480">`